# How to transform WPF app into silent installer

Tags: c#, wpf, silent-installer

I have an installer written with `WPF` and my job is to  transform it into silent installer which will be run from `Cmd line` with in line parameters.

Can you suggest me anything that I can read/check for help or suggestion where to search for anything usefull  for my case?

Comment: http://www.programcall.com/24/dotnet/silent-installation-of-any-application-using-cs.net.aspx

Comment: What *can* you do already? Can you read parameters from the command line? Did you separate your GUI from your program logic? Why did you use WPF to build an installer in the first place?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes app can read command line parameters. I think about some hybrid app which completely new logic for silent install with command line switch. Is it a good idea? According to the second question it wasn't my decision. Company created this installer some time ago. And now I got a job to create silent installer.

Comment: Does the installer do anything that could not be done with normal installer tools like WiX or any other of that sort? Because simply put, you are using the wrong tool. Having a silent, command line driven installer is an automatic feature you get with any installer software. They were reinventing the wheel when they used WPF and now you are tasked to reinvent it all over *again*.

Comment: This installer gets as a parameter an xml where is a list of path to other installers that should be ran  and dependencies which should be checked before. Its some sort of Generic installer which run other silently. And my Job is to make silent this generic also. It must be written in C# and changes to installer logic are unwelcome ( big risk to damage something)

Comment: Then I suggest you give it your best try and come here when you encounter problems. "Silent" just means you don't have a UI. If the application is MVVM, you could just call your VM directly and set all values and execute the commands.